# Laravel 4: use Facade in custom Class

Tags: php, class, laravel, facade

I'm developing an app using Laravel 4 and I have a question I'd like to be asked before fully commit to it.

I've created some custom classes and facades that has been added with success to laravel's configuration file.

For example:

```
namespace Helpers;

class Ftp {

    public function connect($data)
    {
        // Do something
    }

}
```

I'm actually using the php's `use` statement to access to the facades as I do commonly in Laravel:

```
namespace Helpers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;

class Ftp {

    public function Connect($data)
    {
        $file = File::get('text.txt');
            ...
    }

}
```

Now what's the correct way to use laravel's facades inside a custom class? I don't feel that this is a good choice, expecially thinking about the testability. Any suggestion is appreciated!

Comment: Why wouldn't it be good for testability? You can just do `File::shouldReceive('get')->once()->with('text.txt')->andReturn('foo');`

Comment: Make `$file` an argument if you wish to test with different files

Comment: @crynobone That's right, laravel's facade has built-in mock methods, I forgot about that.

Comment: @OneTrickPony You're right too, that was a stupid example by me, a more suited case could be the need to use the Validator's facade before proceed.

Answer (score 5):

Just use File. In app/config/app.php the facades gets aliases.

```
<?php namespace Helpers;

class Ftp {

    public function Connect($data)
    {
        $file = \File::get('text.txt');
        ...
    }

}
```

Comment: Absolutely this is the answer, "\" helping to resolve namespaces, thanks.

Comment: you can add "use File;" as well. The "\" kills my syntax highlighting.

Comment: \ doesnt kill syntax highlighting if your editor is any good.

Comment: It kills any attempt to provide code introspection, auto-complete, and proper refactoring in a decent IDE, though.

Comment: Huh? This does not make sense. \ is the namespace. Any decent IDE can handle this 5.3 PHP feature